# autocomplete run only once when page load or on one letter is typed but only once

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var Employees = function(request, response) {
            var value1 = document.getElementById('<%= txtEmployeeID.ClientID %>').value.split(" ");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "WebService.asmx/GetEmployees",
                data: "{'keywords':'" + value1 + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    //alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
        $('#<%= txtEmployeeID.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true, source: Employees
        });
    });
```

this is code for autocomplete to get value from database.

this runs when each letter is typed and then values are filtered .

i am looking for autocomplete that will load all employee name in var Employee at start then no need to retry filtering autocomplete will do it by autometically filter as a functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jquery AutoComplete function always filters from the source that you are passing as a parameter to it. If you pass an array as a source, it always look in that array to filter.

In your case, the source is a function, which fetches a new array (filtered array) as soon as you type.

All You have to do is to fetch the array and store in a variable and then pass that array to autocomplete plugin.

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Employees = [];
    var value1 = document.getElementById('<%= txtEmployeeID.ClientID %>').value.split(" ");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebService.asmx/GetEmployees",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                Employees = data.d; 
                $('#<%= txtEmployeeID.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
                    autoFocus: true, source: Employees
                });
            },
            error: function(result) {
                //alert("Error");
            }
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could fetch the employees, store the result in an array and provide this array as the [option source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

Answer (score 1):

Add the option select

```
select( event, ui ):function(){
$(this).disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple demo with source code for caching the response and checking to see if the data has already been retrieved or not. Using this set up you don't need to write estra code to retrieve the values in advance

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache

Click on "VIew Source"